# Array Map and onPress doesn't trigger

Tags: react-native, stateless

I am having trouble to make array.map work with inside onPress. 
Here is my code:

```
return(
 {Array.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <Card
                style={styles.card}
                onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}
                key={i}
              >
              </Card>
             }
})
```

Problem is, that onPress doesn't trigger at all. If I place Card outside map function, it works fine. 
Why is this happening? I understand if I don't use arrow functions it won't have those render properties inside map. but I do use arrow functions ?

UPDATE:
I narrowed it to the style property. for some reason when I add 5% margin as my style, onPress doesn't get triggered

Comment: Did you try putting console.log() inside {} ?

Comment: onPress with cards expects void function. If I out console log instead, it gets triggered on card render for each element